# list.remove() tool doesn't remove what it should

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a list containing the numbers from 1-10.

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

I now want to remove all numbers smaller than 5.

```
for i in list:
    if i < 5:
        list.remove(i)
```

If i now print the list,

```
print list
```

I get this:

```
[2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

which seems very odd to me. I may be missing something or just overlooking a simple mistake, but I don't see it.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You're modifying the list as you iterate over it, this is why you get this behaviour

Comment: Don't remove items form a sequence you are currently iterating over. You will get unexpected results.

Comment: If your list is ordered as in your example, you can just `print list[5:]`

Comment: print list[5:] wont give the desired output rather its giving [8, 9, 10]

Comment: On what basis - question is marked as a duplicate? Its not duplicate at all. Lets try to think about the new questions before flagging it duplicate.